# Sliding hamburger menu children doesn't slide with parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently creating a sliding navigation menu that comes up when you click the hamburger icon. However, I cannot seem to get the `<a>` children to slide with the parent div.

Here are images of what it currently looks like. [What it looks like when the menu is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvLUn.png) and [What it looks like when the menu is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwsqS.png).

The two `<a>` elements stay at their place and doesn't move.

Here's what the code looks like the css

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .wrapper > .BurgerMenu {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 60;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .BurgerMenu > .BurgerContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2rem;
  }

  .BurgerMenu > .BurgerContent > a {
    /* color: rgb(50, 50, 50); */
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
  }
```

and the other

```
<div ref={ref} className="wrapper">
  <div className="BurgerMenu">
    <div className="BurgerContent">
      {navItems.map((navItem) => (
        <a key={navItem.name} onClick={(e) => handleClick(navItem.to)(e)}>
          {navItem.name}
        </a>
       ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two anchor tags are inside the div with `BurgerContent` class, which has an absolute position. This means it's always going to be in an absolute position relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

In this case it may either be the parent with position relative when it's visible (the div with class `BurgerMenu`), or the document body if there aren't any other positioned ancestors. Both are similarly positioned, so you won't see a difference.

You probably don't want to use absolute positioning for this.